# Disable extended text selection keys programmatically C winapi

Tags: c, winapi, console

I am writing a text editor that works in the console. For highlighting text I'd like to use Shift+[Arrow key] but I am being blocked by the built-in text selection functionality of the console and it seems that it gets processed before the key event can be read with `ReadConsoleInput`. I found an old question that suggested I disable it manually from the console options, I tried that but it did not even work and if it did I can't settle for that as solution. I know the Windows version of VIM does not have this issue but I have no clue how it solves it.

Comment: ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE ?

Comment: @Anders that flag is used to disable selection via mouse, not keyboard. I already have that and I am asking how to disable selection via keyboard shortcuts (extended edit keys).